# Root check identifies some android non devices as rooted - Dotfuscator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dotfuscator

I'm using Preemptive protection **dotfuscator** for Root detection in my Android App, it works fine but it detects some **non-rooted** devices as **rooted**. How do I solve this?

**Devices detect as rooted**

Samsung A72, Samsung A50, Samsung S20, Huawei P30

I'm using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2019 for implementation

Comment: If you are using the Trail or paid version, file a support ticket: https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support

Comment: Raised a ticket with support and they have replied back saying this is a bug in dotfuscator 6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in dotfuscator 6.4